# How to fix the "Getting unknown property" error when using form fields from a DB in Yii2?

Tags: php, yii2, active-form, form-fields

I would like to implement a solution where the field types of a form are coming from the database.

My form is an `ActiveForm` with a model.

I was adding the following to the DB:

```
formfield: textInput
```

and this to the form:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'rgw')->{$model->rrgw->formfield}(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
```

this is the only way it works, and only for textinput. As soon as I delete `(['maxlength' => true])` it's not working anymore and I get the error:

> Getting unknown property: yii\bootstrap\ActiveField::textInput

Furthermore, if I want a checkbox or something else, `(['maxlength' => true])` is not wanted, right?

So I was trying to add `()` to the DB like this:

```
formfield: textInput()
```

I'm still getting error:

> Getting unknown property: yii\bootstrap\ActiveField::textInput()

How can I get rid of the `()` part in Yii and move this to the DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`textInput()` and `checkbox()` are methods, so you need to use `()` to indicate that you want a methods instead of property.

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'rgw')->{$model->rrgw->formfield}() ?>
```

Comment: Because `()` will be interpreted as a part of property name. So you're looking `textInput()` property instead of `textInput` method.

Comment: ok, and how can I handle e.g `['maxlength' => true]` or any other options then? Because this way it doesn't seem to work: `$form->field($model, 'rgw')->{$model->rrgw->formfield}($model->rrgw->ffoption)`? Or if if I want a widget?